# Looking for a function that gives me all weekdays (monday, tuesday...) based on a variable "year"

Tags: sql, sql-server, dayofweek, week-number

As the title says I'm looking for a function in SQL-Server to retrieve all weekdays, based on a variable set as a year.

I know there should be two useful functions for this case, but I don't know how to use them properly nor I am good at writing functions in SQL:

`SELECT DATENAME(dw, GETDATE())` and `SELECT DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())`

I am expecting something like this:

```
--------------------------
| DATA       | GIORNO    |
--------------------------
| 01/01/2020 | Wednesday |
--------------------------
| 02/01/2020 | Thursday  |
--------------------------
```

EDIT:

Suraj Kumar gave me a suggestion and I'm stuck here:

```
DECLARE @date date = getdate();

SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'd') AS DATA
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) AS GIORNO
```

What I need to do now is to convert the DATA field to the italian format (day/month/year) and return a table with two field like I've explained before this edit...

Comment: So what's *wrong* with `DATENAME`? That appears to do *exactly* what you want. `DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20200101')` returns `'Wednesday'`.

Comment: What does this talk about `year` have anything to do with the question? Sample data and desired results would help out quite a bit here. Your current sample/desired-results are easily solved with `DateName` so I'm suspecting there is more to the question than that.

Comment: What you will pass like from date and to date or a week number in an integer.

Comment: Dates don't have a format, they are (stored as) binary values. The format of the date is defined in the presentation layer.

Comment: For display purpose you can convert date in different format as varchar as shown on this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the functions as shown below if you want to get a week name for a given date in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @date datetime = getdate();
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'dddd') AS Result;

SELECT 
    FORMAT(@date, 'dddd') as Result

SELECT DATENAME(weekday, @date) AS Result

SELECT {fn DAYNAME(@date)} AS Result;
```

Comment: `DATENAME` is a far better choice than `FORMAT`. `FORMAT` is known to be a poor performer.